# Not able to call public static void class within C# program

Tags: c#

I am building a text adventure game and am incorporating a turn-based battle portion into it, but the console essentially freezes when I try to call the public static void for that part. Not getting any errors. The battle portion is called SauronBattle();
If I make a separate program with just the SauronBattle code it runs completely fine, so it seems to be just an issue of it not being called properly. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace textAdventure2


{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            gameTitle();
            first();

        }

        public static void gameTitle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You, a first-year Goshen College student, wake up in your dorm on a Monday morning to the " +
                "sound of a harp playing off in the distance. You rub your eyes, get out of bed, and open your dorm " +
                "door to see what’s going on. As you open the door, a rush of warm, prairie-scented air fills the room. " +
                "You look out and are shocked to not see the hallway, but rather what looks like the shire? You close the door " +
                "behind you and your room slowly dissolves into the background. You stand in the middle of the prairie, " +
                "taking in the tall grasses and gentle breeze. A hobbit approaches you.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to speak to the hobbit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            first();

        }




        public static void first()
        {
            string choice;

            Console.WriteLine("'Uh, hello?' You both say to each other. After a short pause, the hobbit aks: 'Where do you come from?' ");
            Console.WriteLine("You don't usually just give this info out to strangers, but this hobbit seems friendly enough. What would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Tell the hobbit where you are from");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Ask the hobbit to explain where you are");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Run away, this hobbit seems up to no good");
            Console.Write("Choice: ");
            choice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            Console.Clear();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                case "tell hobbit":
                case "tell":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("“Uhm, I’m from Ohio originally but I go to school here in Goshen, it’s a " +
                            "small liberal-arts college with a passion for compassionate peacemaking and restorative justice. " +
                            "Am I in the Lord of the Rings right now?” ");
                        Console.WriteLine("The hobbit's eye widen in fear and disbelief. 'Just as Gandalf had said!' The hobbit thought to himself.");
                        Console.WriteLine("You, you, I was told about you. Sauron’s forces are growing stronger each day, and he plans to take over all of " +
                            "middle-earth. A prophecy from the elves spoke of a compassionate peacemaker from Goshen, who would go to Sauron and convince him " +
                            "that violence is never the answer.'");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        second();
                        break;
                    }
                case "2":
                case "ask hobbit":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You ask the hobbit to explain where you are and what's going on.");
                        Console.WriteLine("He says, 'Well, this is the shire, it is a place in Middle-Earth. What's going on is that Sauron's forces are growing stronger " +
                            "each day. Sauron is all that is evil in this world. We had heard from Gandalf that a compasionate peacemaker from Goshen" +
                            "would come and try to reconcile with Sauron, convincing him that violence is never the answer. ");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        second();
                        break;
                    }
                case "3":
                case "run":
                case "run away":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You quickly sprint away but immediately fall flat on your face after tripping over a potato. The hobbit laughs.");
                        Console.WriteLine("'You're nothing like I was expecting,' said the hobbit. ");
                        Console.WriteLine("You ask the hobbit what he was expecting.");
                        Console.WriteLine("Oh, well, it's just Sauron’s forces are growing stronger each day, and he plans to take over all of " +
                            "middle-earth. A prophecy from the elves spoke of a compassionate peacemaker from Goshen, who would go to Sauron and convince him " +
                            "that violence is never the answer.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        second();
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("That's not an option silly! Try again");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to restart.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        first();
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }


        public static void second()

        {
            string choice;

            Console.WriteLine("'I can bring you to Gandalf if you wish to learn more,' the hobbit tells you.");
            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Meet Gandalf");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Ask the hobbit to take you back to your Goshen College dorm, you're scared and sick of this place");
            Console.Write("Choice: ");
            choice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            Console.Clear();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                case "Meet gandalf":
                case "meet":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The hobbit walks you up and over the hills for what feels like hours. Finally, you reach his house.");
                        Console.WriteLine("'Right this way,' he says, gesturing you indoors.");
                        Console.WriteLine("You duck, the ceiling being much too short for your human stature. The smell of pipe-weed and a warm fire hits your nose," +
                            "and then you see him,  Gandalf, gently rocking in a Wicker chair by the fire. ");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        gandalf();
                        break;
                    }
                case "2":
                case "go back home":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("'Alright Mr Hobbit, I'm sick of this place. I won't be able to stop Sauron and am afraid I'll die trying. Can you please just take" +
                            "me back to my dorm so I can forget about this place.'");
                        Console.WriteLine("The hobbit answers, 'Oh well of course sweetheart! You should have let me know sooner. If I snap my fingers you'll go right back to " +
                            "bed in your college dorm. Be warned though, you may end up back here if the world wills it to be.' ");
                        Console.WriteLine("Yes, yes, please just send me back. I can't take it anymore!");
                        Console.WriteLine("*SNAPS*");
                        Console.WriteLine(".................................................................");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        gameTitle();
                        break;
                    }


                default:
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Command is invalid...");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to restart.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        first();
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        public static void gandalf()
        {
            string CharacterName = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Well hello there young GC student. I've been waiting for you. What do they call you?");
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name");

            CharacterName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Yes," + CharacterName + ", I'm delighted to finally meet. I believe this young hobbit has told you about this " +
                "prophecy from the elves already. I am willing to offer you protection as well as guidance on your journey to Sauron, if you believe" +
                " you are ready.");
            third();
        }

        public static void third()
        {
            string choice;

            Console.WriteLine("'Well, I've made it this far already, I might as well see what I can do to help,' you say to Gandalf.");
            Console.WriteLine("'That is excellent news my dear GC student! I have packed you with all the necessities you will need on this journey. " +
                "Please, you must begin this journey at once. I will send the hobbit along with you as well. Remember, if you choose the wrong path " +
                "or make an incorrect decision, Sauron will sense your location and come to kill you. Be careful! '");
            Console.WriteLine("Gandalf hurriedly pushes you out the door and plops the pack onto your back. He gives you one final glance, then mounts his " +
                "horse and disappears into the sunset. You begin your journey");
            Console.WriteLine(".........................................................................................................");
            Console.WriteLine("You walk along the East Road as the darkness begins to envelop all around you. You hear the sound of horse hooves hitting " +
                "the cobblestone in front of you, getting closer to you.");
            Console.WriteLine("'A Ringwraith!' Shouts the hobbit. What do you do!?");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Stand your ground and fight the Ringwraith");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Run for cover, hide under a tree off the road");
            Console.WriteLine("Choice: ");
            choice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            Console.Clear();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case "1":
                case "fight ringwraith":
                case "fight":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You quickly realize you have zero fighting skills as you are a passionate peacemaker.");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        gameOver();
                        break;
                    }
                case "2":
                case "run and hide":
                case "hide":
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You throw yourself by a large tree trunk moments before the Ringwraith is able to see you. " +
                            "You hear the soft footsteps hitting the road," +
                            "then stopping near you. Your heart beats out of your chest, but just as you think he's about to" +
                            " spot you, the Ringwraith sprints away in the opposite " +
                            "direction. You continue on your journey...");

                        Console.ReadLine();
                        RiddleAttempt();
                        break;

                    }


            }


        }
       

        public static void RiddleAttempt()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(".........................................................");
            Console.WriteLine("A small creature approaches you, and says she knows a shortcut to Sauron's lair. If you answer her riddle correctly" +
                ", she will fly you to Sauron on her gigantic eagle. If you answer incorrectly, she will kill you.");
            Console.WriteLine("'A delicious item sold at Mexican restaurants, and a furry feline friend. Together they make a fun palindrome.' ");
            Console.WriteLine("Please type your answer to the riddle and hit enter:");
            string Riddleword = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Riddleword == "tacocat")
                SauronBattle();
            else
                gameOver();

        }

        public static void SauronBattle()
        {
            int playerHealth = 20;
            int enemyHealth = 20;

            while (playerHealth > 0 && enemyHealth > 0) ;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have " + playerHealth + "health.");
                Console.WriteLine("The enemy has" + enemyHealth + "health.");
                Console.WriteLine("Write 'attack' to attack Sauron or 'block' to block an enemy attack");

                string choice = Console.ReadLine();
                int enemyDamage = new Random().Next(1, 4);

                if (choice == "attack") ;
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You attacked for 2 damage!");
                    enemyHealth -= 2;
                    Console.WriteLine("The enemy attacked for " + enemyDamage + "damage!");
                    playerHealth -= enemyDamage;
                }
                if (choice == "block") ;
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You blocked against the attack!");
                    Console.WriteLine("The enemy would've dealt " + enemyDamage + "damage!");
                }

            }
        }





        public static void gameOver()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Sauron senses your location.");
            Console.WriteLine("You die a quick death");
            Console.WriteLine("The End?");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            gameTitle();
        }

        public static void youWin()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You convince Sauron that violence is never the answer.");
            Console.WriteLine("'You're right,' he says. 'I am a good guy now.'");
            Console.WriteLine("All of middle-earth is saved and you are shot back to your home.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            gameTitle();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: All methods are 'public static void'. Which one freezes the execution?

Comment: `while (playerHealth > 0 && enemyHealth > 0) ;` - the semicolon here is treated as an empty statement. Does the code work if you remove that semicolon?

Comment: learn to use the debugger, (assuming Visual Studio). If program stuck do Debug>Break all. This will break into the program and show what its currently doing

Comment: I love this game, the first program I ever wrote was something like this. I think @JoeSewell has the right idea - the semicolon after the while() statement might be sending you into an infinite loop

Comment: glad to see that someone is trying to learn programming in the coolest way. Just as i did several years ago.
Nothing to do here tho- Joe is completely right. Dont put semicolon everywhere, especially near loops :) Best regards

Comment: Also, no `;` after an `if(...)`